# Recuperar información mediante Autentificación con Facebook en Flutter

Tags: flutter, facebook-api, dependencias, facebook-graph-api

Estoy usando la dependencia: flutter_facebook_login: 3.0.0, y logro realizar la autentificación y guardar datos en Firebase.

Este código funciona, guardo el correo electrónico y la uid, el problema es cuando quiero guardar el nombre, el apellido y la foto de perfil.

```
Future _handleLogin() async {
FacebookLoginResult _result = await _facebookLogin.logIn(['email']);
switch (_result.status) {
  case FacebookLoginStatus.cancelledByUser:
    print("Cancelado por el usuario");
    break;
  case FacebookLoginStatus.error:
    print("error");
    break;
  case FacebookLoginStatus.loggedIn:
    FacebookAccessToken _accessToken = _result.accessToken;
    AuthCredential _credential =
        FacebookAuthProvider.credential(_accessToken.token);
    var a = await _auth.signInWithCredential(_credential);{

    setState(() async {
      User user = a.user;
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('users')
          .doc(user.uid)
          .set({
        'uid': user.uid,
        'email': user.email,
        'name': "Prueba",
        'lastName': "Apellido"
      });
      Navigator.push(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => WelcomePage()));
    });
    break;
  default:
}
```

Leí la documentación del paquete: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_facebook_login

Y menciona que use las siguientes lineas

```
var graphResponse = await http.get(
        'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/me?fields=name,first_name,last_name,email,picture.height(200)&access_token=${_accessToken.token}');
    var profile = json.decode(graphResponse.body);
    print('response : ${profile}');
```

El problema es que me marca el siguiente error:

**Error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uri'.- 'Uri' is from 'dart:core'.**

Finalmente, para guardar la foto, tenia pensado realizarlo de esta manera:

```
await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('usersPhoto')
      .doc(user.uid)
      .set({
    'uid': user.uid,
    'photo': "Photo"
  });
```

¿Como podría corregir el error marcado y asignar a el documento el nombre y apellido, asi como guardar la foto?

Comment: Si ya estas haciendo la comunicación de **Facebook** con **Firebase** puedes obtener el nombre directamente de tu objeto `User`

Comment: me parece que también puedes obtener la foto del usuario con el objeto de, podrías intentar con `photoUrl`

Comment: user.displayName obtiene el nombre y apellidos; como lo podría separar para guardar el nombre y el apellido en campos diferentes?

Comment: Lo arreglé con un split y guardando en un array; gracias.